# mod_rewrite prevents mod_DAV_SVN access, CPanel CentOS server

Tags: apache, module, centos, cpanel, mod-dav-svn

I followed the tutorial on http://sven.webiny.com/subversion-on-cpanel-3-with-centos-55-and-easyapache-32/ to allow mod_dav_svn (HTTP) access to SVN Repositories on my server.

Everything works fine, But the problem is on those hosts having .htaccess mod_rewrite on their web roots (like Wordpress for example), The mod_rewrite supersedes DAV_SVN and location directive (of Apache Conf.), Which is boring and stops me from being able to make /svn location use DAV_SVN.

A target example site is abiusx.com which doesn't always work on http://abiusx.com/svn

Comment: See this question/answer pair for a description on how to make mod_rewrite work with mod_dav_svn: http://serverfault.com/questions/79938/how-can-i-configure-apache-to-redirect-a-subdirectory-to-a-subversion-repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer was, you can't put another handler on roots of your virtual host, unless you specify all the error handler documents:

```
<IfModule dav_svn_module>
<IfModule authz_svn_module>
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.1 178.162.154.252 178.162.154.252:443>
       ServerName abiusx.com
       SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/server.key
ErrorDocument 400 default
    ErrorDocument 401 default
    ErrorDocument 403 default
    ErrorDocument 404 default
    ErrorDocument 405 default
    ErrorDocument 408 default
    ErrorDocument 410 default
    ErrorDocument 411 default
    ErrorDocument 412 default
    ErrorDocument 413 default
    ErrorDocument 414 default
    ErrorDocument 415 default
    ErrorDocument 500 default
    ErrorDocument 501 default
    ErrorDocument 502 default
    ErrorDocument 503 default

<Location />
    Options -All
    DAV svn
    SVNParentPath /home/abiusx/svn/

    AuthzSVNAccessFile /home/abiusx/svn/conf/authz
    Satisfy Any
    Require valid-user
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "AbiusX Subversion"
    AuthUserFile /home/abiusx/svn/conf/.htpasswd
    SVNAutoversioning on 
</Location>
</VirtualHost> 


## valid certificate
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```